# Numbers with same even and odd digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Show that there are exactly $281250$ six-digit numbers that have three even numbers and three odd numbers.

My answer is: $1000000\cdot \binom{6}{3}\cdot \left( \dfrac12 \right)^6-100000\cdot \binom{5}{2}\cdot \left( \dfrac12 \right)^5$.

Mi reasoning is: from $000000$ to $999999$, there are $1.000.000$ numbers. But those that start with $0$ must be subtracted because they would not be $6$-digit numbers. Then we have $1.000.000\times 1/2$ you take off all the ones that are not even in the first digit. $1/2$ all the ones that are not even in the second digit. $1/2$ all the ones that are not even in the third digit And now $(1/2)^3$ all the ones that are not odd in the fourth fifth and sixth digit. Then $\binom{6}{3}$ as they will be the different combinations of the $3$ even numbers and over the $6$ positions. Once you have done all this, you have to subtract all the ones that start with $0$. To do this by a similar reasoning we take the $100.000$ numbers that start with $0$. We multiply by $1/2$ and $1/2$ to subtract those that are not even numbers from the first and second positions and then $(1/2)^3$ to remove those that are not odd from the rest of the positions. And then we multiply it either by $\binom{5}{2}$ of the different combinations of the $2$ pairs between the five digits or $\binom{5}{3}$ of the different combinations of the $3$ odd numbers over the $5$ digits (as we see it is the same $\binom{5}{2}$ as $\binom{5}{3}$).

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your answer as $$5^3\cdot5^3\cdot {6 \choose 3}-5^2\cdot5^3\cdot {5 \choose 2}$$ and explaining it by

> the number of six digit strings with three digits even and three digits odd, minus the number of six digit strings where the leading digit is $0$ and two of the others are even and three odd

suggests to me that your answer is correct